# Publisher information is "Not Available" in a BHO developed using .Net for Internet Explorer

Tags: .net, certificate, bho, sign, publisher

I have searched a lot on here on SOF as well as on MSDN forums but unfortuntely no method could work for me. Here is the problem and the methods applied.

1. I developed a toolbar using .Net for Internet Explorer 7. It is registered as BHO (browser Helper Object" using C# installer code that follows.
2. I am using MSI setup and custom install class file to register the BHO. Here is how i am doing it.
3. I have signed both the dll, generated and signed both the MSI and the EXE for the MSI. After installation i verify in c:\Program Files\My Test Extension\ that my extension has digital signature as well.

**Problem:**

The problem is: When i goto "Managed Addons" in Internet Explorer 7 Options, i see my extension/toolbar under "Not Available" instead of company name as set in Extension/assembly properties. The "Publisher" is not available when i click "more information".

**Please tell how can i set "Publisher Information"? I am using key and valid certificate issued by Verisign Inc,.**

Please tell if i am doing something wrong or missing something. Here is my installer/registration code.

```
            string name = t.Name;
        string help = t.Name;
        rkClass.SetValue(null, name);
        rkClass.SetValue("MenuText", name);
        rkClass.SetValue("HelpText", help);

        rkLMClass.SetValue(null, name);
        rkLMClass.SetValue("MenuText", name);
        rkLMClass.SetValue("HelpText", help);

        rkInprocServer32.SetValue(null, "mscoree.dll");
        rkInprocServer32.SetValue("ThreadingModel", "Both");
        rkInprocServer32.SetValue("Class", t.FullName);
        rkInprocServer32.SetValue("Assembly", "MyTestExtension, Version=1.0.0.0");
        rkInprocServer32.SetValue("RuntimeVersion", "v2.0.50727");

        rkLMInprocServer32.SetValue(null, "mscoree.dll");
        rkLMInprocServer32.SetValue("ThreadingModel", "Both");
        rkLMInprocServer32.SetValue("Class", t.FullName);
        rkLMInprocServer32.SetValue("Assembly", "MyTestExtension, Version=1.0.0.0");
        rkLMInprocServer32.SetValue("RuntimeVersion", "v2.0.50727");

        if (0 != (style & BandObjectStyle.Vertical))
        {
            rkCat.CreateSubKey("{00021493-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
            rkLMCat.CreateSubKey("{00021493-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
        }
        if (0 != (style & BandObjectStyle.Horizontal))
        {
            rkCat.CreateSubKey("{00021494-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
            rkLMCat.CreateSubKey("{00021494-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
        }
        if (0 != (style & BandObjectStyle.TaskbarToolBar))
        {
            rkCat.CreateSubKey("{00021492-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
            rkLMCat.CreateSubKey("{00021492-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
        }
        if (0 != (style & BandObjectStyle.ExplorerToolbar))
            Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar").SetValue(guid, name);

        // register as BHO
        RegistryKey bhoKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects\" + guid);
        bhoKey.SetValue("NoExplorer", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Your help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1):

After set following info in AssemblyInfo.cs file build the DLL.

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Your publisher name")]
```

When you register that DLL then use the following command.

```
regasm /register /codebase YourDLL.dll
```

Now it will show your publisher name in manage addon in IE.

Hope this make more sense.